# Stop reading in an Excel when encountering empty rows

Tags: java, excel, iteration

I currently have a program that reads in an Excel file and processes the data in each sheet through the use of Iterators, inserting each row into a database. When I built and tested the program with the excel file I was provided, everything worked exactly as I expected. I passed the program along to our production server, and now we've discovered that a particular file is causing the program to throw a

`SQLServerException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_V2Product'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.V2Product'. The duplicate key value is ().`

From what I understand,

> The duplicate key value is ()

means that the value being set for the primary key is the empty string. This tells me that the Iterator has passed the rows with tangible data and has found rows that have empty string values in them. Beyond something simple/hacky, such as implementing the following:

```
while(iterator.hasNext(){
    //Iterator runs through, building the object
    //String value = ""; //Primary Key, gets set in the workflow based on column name
    ...
    if(value == null || value.equals("null") || value.equals("")){
        continue;
    }
    ...
    //Would insert data at this point if the primary key field is not null
}
```

is there any way to determine whether the rest of the sheet may contain rows with columns containing empty strings and end the iteration? Or is the best option here to let the iterator run its course through rows and rows of empty strings until we reach the max number of rows a .xlsx can have? Would it be possible to create a counter and implement a condition where if the counter reaches a value of 20, to consider the rest of the sheet empty and break the Iterator loop, without causing any unintentional side effects?

A bit of information about the INSERT process we're using:

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE PrimaryKey = ?", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
preparedStatement.setString(1, value);
```

> ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE

allows us to either update an existing record or insert a new one (resultSet.moveToInsertRow()) if the result set comes back empty.

Comment: which api do you use to read excel? apache poi?

Comment: @Matteo yes, we create the Workbook object from the apache poi WorkbookFactory.create(InputStream) function

Comment: Theorically rowIterator() should understand when there are no more rows or cell (Even though I noticed sometimes it works much better for xlsx than for xls, which is the format you are using?). And have you investigated if the issue is coming from POI reading past last row or may from a missing cell in your specific file? (as u said usually that's working).

Comment: have you tried reading http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator ? there are a few usuful tips (like comparing cell.getCellType() == CellType.BLANK).

Comment: @Matteo Wasn't aware of that documentation so thank you for that! After reading through the iteration section it looks more like it's just about skipping the database step if the specific field happens to be null or empty. Just feels a bit hacky to me so I wasn't satisfied with just skipping it, but it looks like it'll have to do.